# segue.identifier coming up (null)

Tags: objective-c, segue

I am a noobie trying to figure why a segue.identifier is coming up (null), before a segue (prepareForSegue) AND after a segue (unwindToList). What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing? I've set the segue identifier correctly for the scenes involved (in segue attributes).
(Another member here kindly tried to help, but to no avail.)

Here is the code:

In the AddToDoItemViewController.m (source for unwind):

```
    - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"segue identifier sender: %@", segue.identifier);//comes up (null)...??

    self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
    if (sender != self.doneButton) return;//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0 ) {//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
        self.toDoItem.flag = 1;//this code works fine if not conditional in unwind scene
    }
}
```

In the ToDoListViewController.m (destination for unwind):

```
    - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ToDoListViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    NSLog(@"segue from: %@", source);//no problem here... correct scene is logged
    NSLog(@"segue identifier: %@", segue.identifier);//comes up (null)...??
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addItemScene"]) {//condition is always FALSE...??
        if (source.toDoItem.flag == 1) {
        ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
        if (item != nil) {
            [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"(a different scene"]) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: How are these segues being triggered?  Are they invoked manually in code, or in a storyboard?

Comment: In the storyboard, I think... a "Cancel" button that triggers an unwind segue "unwindToList" or a "Done" button that does the same. These can be seen in the Connections Inspector and are associated with the following code in AddToDoItemViewController.m. Here is that code:

`@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton;
@property ToDoItem *toDoItem;

@end`

Comment: Hey, Dan... any ideas about this issue? Just when you get a minute... much appreciated! Cheers,

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The segue identifier is fine when it gets to prepareForSegue, but it is null when it gets to the unwind. Since I use the same modal view for several different purposes, I rely on the segue identifier to tell me which version the user was just in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution/workaround to the unwind part of the problem:

Let's say I have two view controller classes, TopViewController and ModalDialogViewController. And there are three segues from TopViewController to ModalDialogViewController, created in the storyboard.

In ModalDialogViewController.h I create an enumerated type:

```
typedef enum { MD_aboutDialog, MD_helloWorldDialog, MD_anotherDialog } MD_dialogType;
```

Then I add a property for it:

```
@interface ModalDialogViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) EL_dialogType dialogType;
@end
```

Each of the dialog types is associated with a segue identifier that is entered in the storyboard; I make pound-defines for them in ModalDialogViewController.h:

```
#define MD_segueAboutDialogId       @"AboutDialogSegueId"
#define MD_segueHelloWorldDialogId  @"HelloWorldDialogSegueId"
#define MD_segueAnotherDialogId     @"AnotherDialogSegueId"
```

In the topViewController, I have my prepareForSegue and "unwind from dialog" methods:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MD_dialogType dialogType;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:MD_segueAboutDialogId]) {
        dialogType = MD_aboutDialog;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:MD_segueHelloWorldDialogId]) {
        dialogType = MD_helloWorldDialog;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:MD_segueAnotherDialogId]) {
        dialogType = MD_anotherDialog;
    }
    else
        return; // shouldn't get here

    ModalDialogViewController *dialogController = (ModalViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    dialogController.dialogType = dialogType;

   // Do whatever other setup you need
}
```

Meanwhile, when you unwind:

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromDialogOnOK:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ModalDialogViewController *dialogController = (ModalViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;

    if (dialogController.dialogType == MD_aboutDialog) {
        // Do Something
    }
    else if (dialogController.dialogType == MD_helloWorldDialog) {
        // Do Something Else
    }
    else if (dialogController.dialogType == MD_anotherDialog) {
        // Do Something Else Entirely
}

- (IBAction)unwindFromDialogOnCancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ModalViewController *dialogController = (ModalViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;

    if (dialogController.dialogType == MD_anotherDialog) {
        // Take any action needed if they canceled
    }
}
```

Of course, this solution only works if your segue identifier is non-null in the prepareForSegue method. And there may be a reason our segues have null identifiers on the unwind - and if that was solved, there would be no reason to do this. But it's good to know that we have full access to both controllers, so that we can use their properties to pass information.

An addition if you still can't get a non-null segue identifier in prepareForSegue would be to have a corresponding dialogType property in the TopViewController that you then use to set the corresponding dialogType in the ModalDialogViewController, since you have access to both controllers.